# How to print a float variable using the % formatting?

Tags: python

I'm using Python 3.7.1 on Windows.
When I print a float variable using the % formatting. only the natural part is printed.
Here is an example:

```
result_2 = 4.523529411764706
statement_2a = "Your text contains an average length of %d letter(s) per words." % result_2

print(result_2)
print(statement_2a)
```

This gives the following result:

```
4.523529411764706
Your text contains an average length of 4 letter(s) per words.
```

But what I actually want is:

```
Your text contains an average length of 4.5235 letter(s) per words.
```

1. How do I prevent the print() function from practically deleting the decimal numbers?
2. How to round the number to four decimal digits

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Format with `% round(result_2, 4)`

Comment: You need `%1.4f` instead of `%d` in the string

Comment: A simple solution would be to use `%s` to print number exactly as string

Comment: @DavidG Thanks! That's worked!

Comment: @skaul05 Awesome, didn't know that one either! Thanks!

Comment: @user2357112 out of interest then - if you don't like the % formatting - how would you have done it?

Comment: @skytt4: `.format` formatting.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you try print float number, use %f instead of %d.
This code will print the number to 4 decimal places:

```
result_2 = 4.523529411764706
statement_2a = "Your text contains an average length of %.4f letter(s) per words." % result_2

print(result_2)
print(statement_2a)
```

Answer (score 10):

There are several options to evaluate expressions and print them as a string in python.

There are already some good answers, but here are some explicit examples and links to the documentation.

**Formatted string literals (f-strings)**

[f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings) allow you to input expressions which are evaluated at run-time. In the f strings expressions are encased by curly brackets.

As an example:

```
x = 42.222222222

print(f'My value is: {x}')
```

prints `My value is: 42.222222222`.

and with specifying the format:

```
x = 42.222222222

print(f'My value is: {x:.2f}')
```

prints `My value is: 42.22`.

**Str formatting method**

Strings have a built-in [`.format()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) method where you can specify replacement fields with curly brackets.

As an example:

```
x = 42.222222222

print('My value is: {}'.format(x))
```

prints `My value is: 42.222222222`.

and with string formatting:

```
x = 42.222222222

print('My value is: {:.2f}'.format(x))
```

prints `My value is: 42.22`.

**String formatting operator**

[String formatting operator](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting)

As an example:

```
x = 42.222222222

print('My value is: %' % x)
```

prints `My value is: 42.222222222`.

and with string formatting:

```
x = 42.222222222

print('My value is: %.2f' % x)
```

prints `My value is: 42.22`.

See @Felk answer for some more qualitive descriptions of the different methods.

Answer (score 1):

You are using "old-style" formatting and used `%d` as the placeholder. This will represent your number as a decimal number without any fractions. If you want to display floating point numbers, the placeholder is simply `%f`.

If you want to use the variable's string representation, you can also always just use `%s`. But since you are on python 3.7, there are some more modern approaches as well.

- "old-style" formatting: `"%s" % var`
- "new-style" formatting using `format()`: `"{}".format(var)` (Read up on python formatters for details)
- f-strings, which are basically syntactic sugar for `format()`-based string interpolation. You prefix with `f` and put the variables in the string literal itself: `f"{var}"`

Answer (score 0):

A better alternative than `%` formatting would be to use `.format`.

```
result_2 = 4.523529411764706
print(result_2)
print("Your text contains an average length of {} letter(s) per words.".format(result_2))
```

For rounding use `round`

```
result_2 = 4.523529411764706
print(result_2)
print("Your text contains an average length of {} letter(s) per words.".format(round(result_2,4)))
```

But if you feel comfortable with `%` formatting then to print whole number use `%s`

```
result_2 = 4.523529411764706
statement_2a = "Your text contains an average length of %s letter(s) per words." % result_2
print(result_2)
print(statement_2a)
```

For rounding to 4 digits use `%1.4f`

```
result_2 = 4.523529411764706
statement_2a = "Your text contains an average length of %1.4f letter(s) per words." % result_2
print(result_2)
print(statement_2a)
```